# Как сделать анимацию полета стрелы к цели

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Я хочу, чтобы стрела, выпускаемая башней в игре типа TowerDefence, летела не по прямой к врагу, а по дуге: вверх, вниз. Я сделал сам полет и вращение. Вращается стрела так, что на какое бы расстояние она ни летела, все равно успевает провернуться ровно1  раз. Но проблема в том, что у меня стрела крутиться против часовой стрелки, а это подходит только если враг/соперник/монстр находится слева от башни. Если он справа, то стрела, физически корректнее должна крутиться по часовой стрелке. Как правильнее это реализовать? Просто сравнивать координаты по X и задавать вращение, или есть какой-то более умный способ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чисто физику можно сделать если каждый кадр направлять стрелу вниз по формуле ускорение свободного падения (примерно равно 9.8) * дельту кадра, а направление по производной, если мат часть не подкачает, или просто повернутся задом к предыдущей позиции. Если на Юнити, то можно поставить компонент ригидбоди и цент масс на наконечнике (https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/2019.4/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-centerOfMass.html)

Comment: Дельту можно найти по команде Time.deltaTime, или если в FixedUpdate - Time.fixedDeltaTime

Comment: Могу ли я как-то изменить центр масс не из скрипта, а прямо из инспектора. Причем в Rigidbody2D?

Comment: Вроде нет, но сдесь хорошый видос по этой теме: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BmFhSoCxX8g

Answer (score 0):

(Может я чего-то не понимаю в специфике разработки игр)

Физически (IRL) есть "ускорения свободного падения", и задачки про бросание кирпичей в школьных учебниках с формулами. Должно получиться очень естественно.

А хвост у стрелы (если проще) можно повернуть по направлению к прошлой позиции.